# Google Web Font Michroma - Space At The Top

Tags: css, html, google-webfonts

It seems that the Michroma webfont from Google has spacing above the letters, is there any way to change this spacing? It seems as part of the font itself? I have put Tahoma below it to compare the spacing. To show spacing between the 2 fonts, I added a background colour and provided a link to JSFiddle to show this.

HTML

```
   <div>
       <p class="michroma">Michroma</p>
       <p class="main">Tahoma</p>
   </div>
   <div>
       <p class="michroma small">Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules.</p>

       <p class="michroma small">Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca: On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation e plu sommun paroles. Ma quande lingues coalesce, li grammatica del resultant lingue
        es plu simplic e regulari quam ti del coalescent lingues. Li nov lingua franca va esser plu simplic e regulari quam li existent Europan</p>
       <p class="main small">Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules.</p>

       <p class="main small">Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca: On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation e plu sommun paroles. Ma quande lingues coalesce, li grammatica del resultant lingue
        es plu simplic e regulari quam ti del coalescent lingues. Li nov lingua franca va esser plu simplic e regulari quam li existent Europan</p>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Michroma');

.michroma { 
    font-family: 'Michroma', sans-serif;
    font-size: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
 }

 .main { 
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
 }

.small { font-size: 16px; }
```

JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/zerolfc/ofs7vxou/

[image: Illustration of the space above the Michroma webfont]

Comment: Check the css property line-height

Comment: I tried the CSS line-height property and the space at the top of the letters is still there, you can see it when it is selected. https://jsfiddle.net/zerolfc/oyub5b49/